# How to Integrate Jenkins for Junit Project for Native Mobile Apps?

Tags: jenkins, appium, hybrid-mobile-app, junit5

I want to Run End to End for Daily Based  Mode in Appium. 
I am Currently using Selenium+Java+Maven+cucumber+junit for Native app. Is this possible to integrate with Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not. You need a Jenkins agent with a JVM, maven and whatever mobile emulator / real device you want to automate. You can use the standard Jenkins Maven project as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can integrate jenkins, select a "new Item" in jenkins, create a new freestyle project, you can your commands in the "Build" section. To Schedule it on Daily bases you can select the option either "Build Periodically" (if you are not passing any parameters) or Schedule it using "Parameterized Scheduler Plugin" this plugin